# PHP embed image into form

Tags: php, html, forms

I've tried so many different tutorials to try and get this to work but to no avail. This is the code I'm using and currently it works perfectly except when I embed the image. Once I embed the image, the email is not received.

```
<?php

$field_website = $_POST['cf_website'];
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_age = $_POST['cf_age'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_cell = $_POST['cf_cell'];
$field_tutor = $_POST['cf_tutor'];
$field_instrument = $_POST['cf_instrument'];
$field_lesson_type = $_POST['cf_lesson_type'];
$field_no_of_lessons = $_POST['cf_number'];
$field_amount_due = $_POST['cf_amount'];
$field_ref_num = $_POST['cf_ref_num'];

$field_booking_date = $_POST['cf_booking_date'];
$field_start_time = $_POST['cf_start_time'];
$field_end_time = $_POST['cf_end_time'];

$field_booking_date2 = $_POST['cf_booking_date2'];
$field_start_time2 = $_POST['cf_start_time2'];
$field_end_time2 = $_POST['cf_end_time2'];

$field_booking_date3 = $_POST['cf_booking_date3'];
$field_start_time3 = $_POST['cf_start_time3'];
$field_end_time3 = $_POST['cf_end_time3'];

$field_booking_date4 = $_POST['cf_booking_date4'];
$field_start_time4 = $_POST['cf_start_time4'];
$field_end_time4 = $_POST['cf_end_time4'];

if (empty($field_name) && empty($field_email) && empty($field_cell) && empty($field_tutor)) {
    echo 'Please fill in all required fields';
    return false;
}

else{
//process the rest of the form
}

if($field_website != ''){
    echo "Submission Sent - Thank you!";
    return false;
}

else{
//process the rest of the form
}

$mail_to = 'bookings@test.com';

$subject = 'Student Booking';
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($field_email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($field_email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$body_message = '<html><body style="font-family:calibri,sans-serif; font-size:18px">';
$body_message .= '<h2 style="font-weight:600; font-size:27px; border-bottom:dashed 1px #CCC; padding-bottom:10px;">Student Booking</h2>';
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Full Name:</strong> '.$field_name."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Age:</strong> '.$field_age."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">E-mail Address:</strong> '.$field_email."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Cellphone Number:</strong> '.$field_cell."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Tutor Name:</strong> '.$field_tutor."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Instrument to Learn:</strong> '.$field_instrument."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Lesson Type:</strong> '.$field_lesson_type."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Number of Lessons:</strong> '.$field_no_of_lessons."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Amount Due:</strong> R'.$field_amount_due."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Reference Number:</strong> #'.$field_ref_num."</p>\n"."\n";

$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Booking Date:</strong> '.$field_booking_date."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Start Time:</strong> '.$field_start_time."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">End Time:</strong> '.$field_end_time."</p>\n"."\n";

$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">2nd Booking Date:</strong> '.$field_booking_date2."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">2nd Start Time:</strong> '.$field_start_time2."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">2nd End Time:</strong> '.$field_end_time2."</p>\n"."\n";

$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">3rd Booking Date:</strong> '.$field_booking_date3."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">3rd Start Time:</strong> '.$field_start_time3."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">3rd End Time:</strong> '.$field_end_time3."</p>\n"."\n";

$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">4th Booking Date:</strong> '.$field_booking_date4."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">4th Start Time:</strong> '.$field_start_time4."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">4th End Time:</strong> '.$field_end_time4."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '</body></html>';

$autoTo = "$field_email";

$subject_auto = 'Booking Received!';
$headers_auto = "From: " . strip_tags('bookings@test.com') . "\r\n";
$headers_auto .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags('bookings@test.com') . "\r\n";
$headers_auto .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers_auto .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$auto_body = '<html><body style="font-family:calibri,sans-serif; font-size:18px">';
$auto_body .= '<p>Dear '.$field_name."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_body .= '<p>Thank you for booking at We See Musically! Confirmation of your booking details are shown below: '."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_body .= '<p><strong>Tutor Name:</strong> '.$field_tutor."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_body .= '<p><strong>Instrument Chosen:</strong> '.$field_instrument."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_body .= '<p><strong>Lesson Type:</strong> '.$field_lesson_type."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_body .= '<p><strong>Number of Lessons:</strong> '.$field_no_of_lessons."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_body .= '<p>Please note that the amount due is R'.$field_amount_due.' and your reference number is #'.$field_ref_num.'. Please kindly make sure to use your reference number otherwise your booking will not be processed. Once payment has been received, your tutors full residential address as well as your booked dates and times will be emailed to you.  '."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_body .= "<p>We trust you'll have a great tutoring experience at We See Musically!  "."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_body .= '<img src="http://test.com/images/wsm-logo.png" ALT="We See Musically">';
$auto_body .= '</body></html>';


mail($autoTo, $subject_auto, $auto_body, $headers_auto);

mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: how are you sending email ? are you using any library ?

Comment: Just sending it via php.

Comment: show the code for that .. also you are setting content type two times .. there is no need for that .. line 6-9 are not needed

Comment: I've changed the code above to reflect the full php code I'm using as well as removed the original lines 6-9. :)

Comment: Try sending the same email with something like sendgrid or mailchimp's mandrill app. Odds are your smtp server isn't quite up to par with web standards, and whatever email service you are testing with is filtering the content of your emails. I faced a similar issue a few months ago, and switching to sendgrid `magically` resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sending emails is pretty complex so I urge you to use a tested library instead of using PHP's `mail()` function directly.

Some mail services use really old software. They might reject emails which contains lines longer than 70 characters (I've seen this happen) or reject emails with characters outside of ASCII. That's just the top of an iceberg, so it's pretty hard to say what is wrong with your specific message.

If you are going to write your own mail implementation, you should start by reading some relevant RFCs, like the ones mentioned in the PHP manual:

> The following RFCs may be useful: » RFC 1896, » RFC 2045, » RFC 2046,
>   » RFC 2047, » RFC 2048, » RFC 2049, and » RFC 2822.

Or you could just use a library like `Zend\Mail`, `PEAR::Mail`, `SwiftMailer` or `PHPMailer` and rely on the testing done by the developers of those packages.